# Cannot read .style property of undefined on for loop (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, properties, undefined

**THE PROBLEM TO SOLVE:**

I have a slider that has to make an animation between slides and not just go to the nex/prev one instantly.

**SCENARIO:**

(you will find a fiddle with all the code at the end of the question)
I have the next structure on my template (pls look at the fiddle to check the styles):

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="slider">
    <ul id="slide-wrap" @click="nextSlide" @click.middle="prevSlide">
      <li v-for="(slide, index) in slides" :key="index" class="slide">
        <div class="content">
          {{slide.id}}
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in my script, at the mounted() method i define all the variables that i need (included slide):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    const thiss = this;
    this.sliderWidth = document.getElementById('slider').offsetWidth;
    this.sliderList = document.getElementById('slide-wrap');
    this.slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    this.slide = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      thiss.sliderWidth = document.getElementById('slider').offsetWidth;
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      slider: '',
      sliderList: '',
      slide: null,
      count: 0,
      sliderWidth: 0,
      slides: [
        {
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.slides.length;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    call() {
      console.log(this.slide);
    },
    nextSlide() {
      if (this.count < (this.items-1)) {
        this.count = this.count + 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.items; i++ ) {
          this.slide[i].style.transform = 'translateX(- + this.count * this.sliderWidth +px)';
        }
      } else {
        this.count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.items; i++ ) {
          this.slide[i].style.transform = 'translateX(- + this.count * this.sliderWidth +px)';
        }
      }
    },
  },
})
```

the problem is on the nextSlide() method, that throws the error "cannot read property .style of undefined" despite that i checked the variable with the call() method and it returns the elements on the dom, what am i doing wrong?

If you check on the fiddle, at the end of the script is a chunk of commented code with another solution that changes the position of the .slide-wrap element, but i need the new solution to be modifying the translateX(X) property of each .slide element

https://jsfiddle.net/carlosPisarello/hc3rz5g4/10/

Comment: You never apply the `slide` class, so your `querySelectorAll('.slide')` gets zero nodes.

Comment: well, the mounted() method runs when all the DOM is rendered, so when all the iterations of the v-for finish, i call document.QuerySelectorAll('.slide'), the thing is that in fact it is setted properly, but still the browser can't read the property because it recnognizes it as undefined, i say it setted properly because if i make a console.log('this.slide') it returns the right values

Comment: ooooh! such a detail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue handles the `style` attribute for things like this, so you shouldn't be manipulating the DOM directly for that.

All the offsets are the same, so you can just make a computed at the Vue level and apply it to all of them:

```
  <li v-for="(slide, index) in slides" :key="index" class="slide" :style="transform">
```

The computed looks like this:

```
transform() {
  const amount = - this.count * this.sliderWidth;
  const transformArg = `translateX(${amount}px)`;

    return {transform: transformArg};
}
```

And your nextSlide is just:

```
nextSlide() {
  if (this.count < (this.items-1)) {
    this.count = this.count + 1;
  } else {
    this.count = 0;
  }
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hc3rz5g4/31/)

Comment: this looks very cool and a lot cleaner than my solution, i'll try it! 

Thank you!